# Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8 API migration

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a library (not of my own authorship) which is integrated with Tomcat 7 APIs. The [migration guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#Internal_APIs) talks in general terms about it being broadly compatible and suggest looking at the javadocs but this is a bit vague, especially for someone not overly familiar with Tomcat internal APIs. Can anyone point to better migration documentation?

A specific example: the class org.apache.naming.resources.WARDirContext is gone, what replaces it in the new framework?